# Meaning of “to wax loquacious”

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

What does the phrase *to wax loquacious* mean? 
The following line appeared in [an Indian newspaper](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/sahitya-akademi-award-fighting-silence-with-dignified-dissent/article7750250.ece):

> It is an attempt to confront the Prime Minister, who **waxes loquacious** when speaking to the Non-Resident Indians(NRIs) while writers and ordinary citizens are murdered back home.

Comment: So, what does a dictionary tell you?

Answer (score 3):

*Wax* here means to increase.  This is often used in the phrase "the waxing of the moon" to describe the times during which the face of the moon appears to grow from new moon to full moon.  *Loquacious* means talkative.  The link is to an article that comments that the Prime Minister on the occasions he talks to non-resident Indians has a tendency to become increasingly talkative (i.e., he has a lot to say) but on an important issue, those living in India will find him unaccountably silent.

Answer (score 1):

To become more eloquent, to speak 'too much':

To ***[wax](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wax)***  in a figurative sense, means:

> - To speak or write as specified: *"[He] warmed to his most favorite of subjects,**waxed eloquent**, gained in his face a glow of passion" (Paul J. Willis).* (AHD)

[Loquacious](http://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/loquacious):

Meaning: Very talkative, chatty, using lots of words, verbose.

> - Notes: The noun from today's word is loquacity [lo-qwæ-sê-ti] and the adverb loquaciously. A related adjective is loquent "talking, speaking" that turns up mostly in technical writing as in, "Are chimpanzees a loquent species?" This adjective yields a noun, loquency "talk, the ability to speak".
> - The synonym of today's word, talkative, is an accepted lexical violation in that it is made up of a native stem, talk, plus a Latin suffix -ative, two supposedly incompatible constituents. *But perhaps ***I am waxing loquacious myself**  and should stop here to leave room for a few other comments on this interesting word.

(www.alphadictionary.com)

Comment: Beware, you have linked both "wax" and "loquacious" to the definition of "loquacious"!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bunch of silly idioms composed of two words, the first one of which is always "wax" in the sense of "increase."

"Wax loquacious" means getting more and more talkative.

"Wax poetic" means getting more romantic by the minute.

And so forth.

Comment: That's what *wax* means -- increase.  Why is this silly again?

Comment: I don't know. Why are James Bond movies silly? Why are Broadway musicals silly? Why are Philistines silly? It's a quirk of fate.

Comment: You don't know.  I accept that.  If you don't know, then don't put it in your answer.  The OP is likely not a native speaker of English and may take your  comment as serious and thereby think the wording is to be generally considered frivolous.  It's not.

Comment: @deadrat : I don't know WHY it's silly. I just know it IS silly. You can be such a grouch sometimes. Some of the best comments in history are frivolous.

Comment: It's silly to *you* and that's fine.  It's not so silly when you lead the unskilled to believe that people generally will think the usage silly.  They don't.  It's certainly used seriously in the context of the link the OP provided.  This isn't about the general worth of frivolity.  It's about misleading people.

Comment: @deadrat : Well, if you put it that way ... "Silly" was a warning to the OP, meaning "Don't use in polite company if you don't wish to be thought of as a Philistine without a single original idea in your head." Please note that being "thought of" as one is not the same as actually being one; note also that it does matter to some people what others think of them. You can view my "silly" as a euphemism for "poor taste." Or mauveton, if you will. Saying "wax [whatever]" today is a comical demimonde-ish attempt to sound beau-monde.

Comment: Isn't "by the minute" really an idiom, though?  ; )

Comment: If I am not your biggest fan here, I am least your last-ditch defender, but your blithe confidence in yourself may mislead people.  Polite society is not sensitive to silliness but to rudeness.  Philistines aren't unoriginal; they're hostile to culture; silly is not a euphemism for poor taste; it simply means frivolous; the demimonde is that segment of society considered not respectable because of its dubious morality.  Comical is an inapt modifier for it, and it doesn't apply to silly speech.  The use of *wax* you might think stilted or archaic, but its use is not related to fashion.

Comment: And I don't know what *mauveton* is.  Your comment is practically word salad, and it's a perfect example of what I object to.  Native speakers may find your antics with wordplay amusing or annoying, but they're unlikely to be misled.  Novice speakers, not so much.  The OP's cite is not about a silly topic, and it's diction, being Indian-English may sound a bit odd to you, but it's not silly either.  You might try explaining why no one would say seriously, "I'm waxing hungry" without risking confusion.